# Remote VNC from Fedora to Ubuntu

Tags: linux, vnc

PC-A: remote Ubuntu box
PC-B: my local Fedora box

PC-A [via ssh]: 
apt-get install tightvncserver

and i gived a good password

ok!
PC-B: 
yum install vinagre

i flushed all my iptables rule

And i tried to connect with IPADDRESS:5901 from my "PC-B" Fedora box to PC-A.

Well..the good thing is, that vinagre pops a password box, and i can see the wallpaper of the Ubuntu machine. But after giving the good password, nothing happens. I can see the wallpaper, and the mouse is waiting, and waiting..

What am i missing? Either PC-A hasn't any firewall rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to look in ~/.vnc/xstartup on the remote end.  It's possible that you're running something like `twm`, which is somewhat feature-free when it comes to a desktop envrironment.

Also, did you know that the VNC traffic is not encrypted?  Your password and keypresses are being sent in the clear over the network.  Most people tunnel their VNC session over SSH.

Comment: Who are these "most people" you refer to, and how can I get them as my users?

Comment: with this it works: echo 'gnome-session &' >> ~/.vnc/xstartup

Comment: @mattdm: perhaps I should say, most people **who care about security** use VNC over SSH.

Answer (score 0):

Try right clicking on the desktop.  It may open a menu.

I have switched to using RDP for remote access my desktop. Traffic is encrypted and the desktop size is easier to adjust.  Sessions can be dropped and resumed later.  It is available as package, and relatively easy to setup.  Under the hood it is still VNC.

I wrote up my experiences on [Remote Desktops with RDP and VNC](http://www.systemajik.com/blog/remote-desktops-with-vnc-and-rdp/).